# Codename One - error: package com.google.protobuf does not exist

Tags: java, android, codenameone

Further to [Codename One - ProGuard - Duplicate jar entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77154700/codename-one-proguard-duplicate-jar-entry). I've created the native interface and can build and run the code in NetBeans and the Simulator. I've now created similar code under the android project. When I send a build to the builder server, I receive the following error (and more):

`Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/tmp/build1143954818015752843xxx/HHT/src/main/java/com/google/transit/realtime/GtfsRealtime.java:11: error: package com.google.protobuf does not exist
com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite registry) {
^`

GtfsRealtime.java was generated using a supplied *.proto file and protoc via command-line. It uses protobuf. If I understand correctly, I catered for protobuf in the Simulator by adding dependencies to the javese pom.xml. How do I do the same for the android code?

Comment: Since your previous question, have you kept `protobuf-javalite` (but not `protobuf-java`) in your POM? They're distinct runtimes, and you probably want `protobuf-javalite` based on the ExtensionRegistryLite in your error message. Posting your most recent pom.xml will help.

Comment: Also, did you add the dependency in the android pom? Notice that there are native poms that are distinct from the main pom.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog and Jeff Bowman, thanks for your replies. Yes, I have removed the dependency for protobuf-java and retained the one for protobuf-javalite. To be clear, this is in the javase project. I had no dependencies in the android project. So, yes, I can see how that will cause my problem. When I add the dependencies (protobuf-javalite and protobuf-java-util, also required) to the android project and request a build on the build server, my jar size increases from 601Kb to 6801Kb and is rejected. Please see next comment.

Comment: @ShaiAlomg The build error is: android-device: Jar size limit reached for free accounts. I'm unsure why the jar increases by so much (seems to be com.goole.common related) and also thought the maximum size for a jar for a free account was  8.5Mb. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Edit above: com.goole.common should read com.google.common

Comment: That's a limit on the free account to prevent abuse to our servers. You can still do local builds which are a bit more work though.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, thanks. I'll give that a try.